# How can I create and download a zip file using Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm developing an application using Adobe Flex 4.5 SDK, in which the user would be able to export multiple files bundled in one zip file. I was thinking that I must need to take the following steps in order for performing this task:

1. Create a temporary folder on the server for the user who requested the download. Since it is an anonymous type of user, I have to read Sate/Session information to identify the user.
2. Copy all the requested files into the temporary folder on the server
3. Zip the copied file
4. Download the zip file from the server to the client machine

I was wondering if anybody knows any best-practice/sample-code for the task
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ByteArray` class has some methods for compressing, but this is more for data transport, not for packaging up multiple files.

I don't like saying things are impossible, but I will say that this should be done on the server-side. Depending on your server architecture I would suggest sending the binary files to a server script which could package the files for you.

A quick google search for your preferred server-side language and zipping files should give you some sample scripts to get you started.